# Getting "{error: 'Operation `users.findOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms'}" when requesting on my app at localhost

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have 2 folders 'client' and 'server', my express app is running succesfully and connected to mongoDB in server folder using nodemon

[image]

My react server is running in client folder
[image]

when I am requesting on app and making an API call, it is not working for example at sign up user, it is taking alot of time I guess to query at 'findOne()' method which gives this error and heading straight to the catch block.
I am providing all the code:

db.js

```
require('dotenv').config();
const mongoose = require('mongoose'); 
mongoose.set('strictQuery', true);
const mongoURI = process.env.MONGO_URI;

// Connecting to MongoDB Atlas through Mongo URI
const connectToMongo = () => {
    mongoose.connect(mongoURI, () => {  
        console.log('Connected to Mongoose Successfully');
    })
}

module.exports = connectToMongo;
```

index.js

```
const connectToMongo = require('./db');
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
require('dotenv').config();


// calling db.js to connect to MongoDB
connectToMongo();

const app = express()
const port = 5000;

// midleware to use API Endpoints
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

//Available Routes
app.use('/api/auth', require('./Routes/auth'));
app.use('/api/notes', require('./Routes/notes'))


app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`iNotebook listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```

routes.js

/createUser route

```
// Route 1: Create a user using: POST api/auth/createUser. No Login Required.
router.post('/createUser',
    body('name').isLength({ min: 3 }),
    body('email').isEmail(),
    body('password').isLength({ min: 8 }),
    async (req, res) => {

        let success = false;
        //if there is error, return bad rquest and errors
        const errors = validationResult(req);
        if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
            return res.status(400).json({ success, errors: errors.array() });
        }

        try {

            //check whether the user with this email exists already
            // console.log(req.body.email);
            let user = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email });
            //if yes, through an error
            if (user) {
                return res.status(400).json({ success, error: "A user with this email already exist" });
            }

            //hashing password
            const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
            const safePass = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, salt);

            //if not exist already, create a new user
            user = await User.create({
                name: req.body.name,
                email: req.body.email,
                password: safePass
            })

            //generate an Authentication Token and return it as a response
            const data = {
                user: {
                    id: user.id
                }
            }
            const authToken = jwt.sign(data, JWT_Secret);
            success = true;
            res.json({ success, authToken });

        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error.message);
            res.status(500).send({"error": error.message});
        }
    }
);
```

/loginUser route

```
// Route 2: Authenticate a user using: POST api/auth/loginUser. No Login Required.
router.post('/loginUser',
    body('email', 'Enter a valid Email').isEmail(),
    body('password', 'Password cannot be blank').exists(),
    async (req, res) => {
        let success = false;
        
        //if there is error, return bad rquest and errors
        const errors = validationResult(req);
        if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
            return res.status(400).json({success, errors: errors.array() });
        }

        const { email, password } = req.body;
        try {

            //check whether user with this email exist or not 
            let user = await User.findOne({ email });
            //if not, through an error
            if (!user) {
                return res.status(400).json({success, error: "Please try to login with correct credentials" });
            }

            //if exist, compare the entered password
            const passCompare = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
            //if do not match, through an error
            if (!passCompare) {
                return res.status(400).json({success, error: "Please try to login with correct credentials" });
            }

            //if matched, generate an Authentication Token as a response 
            const data = {
                user: {
                    id: user.id
                }
            }
            // res.send(user.id)
            const authToken = jwt.sign(data, JWT_Secret);
            success = true;
            res.status(200).json({success, authToken });
            console.log(res.status(200).json({success, authToken }))

        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error.message);
            res.status(500).send("Internal error occured");
        }

    }
);
```

I have used and run this app before but on another OS and other file structure. I explained the new structure in starting. Now I even deleted my old database at mongodb and made and connected a new one

[image]

This is my MongoURI: `"mongodb+srv://haseeb-sheikh10:<password>@inotebook-cluster.dbrzmnx.mongodb.net/inotebook/?retryWrites=true"`

Answer (score 0):

The `connectToMongo` function must be made `async`, and the you must add `await` on the line :

```
 await mongoose.connect(mongoURI, 
    () => {console.log('Connected to Mongoose Successfully');
 })
```

Also enclose the above code in a try-catch block, to avoid any exceptions/errors while connecting to the DB.

And also, you can ensure that the MongoDB URI has this at the end: `?retryWrites=true`. This would address the timed-out issue on write operations.

To resolve the issue of timed-out on Read operation,

1. try optimizing the query,
2. making the database more efficient, by keeping in mind the indexes.

This issue could also occur when your dataset is extremely large.

Comment: by doing what you told, I am not getting buffer error but the request remains at requesting for forever and dosn't give any response.
I have made and connected a new database, and dataset is empty